# Mixed Content image on Prestashop

Tags: ssl, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I installed an SSL certificate to a website created with Prestashop 1.6.

But it indicates to me that it is not totally safe since there is a request to the logo of the site by HTTP. Checking the code from chrome developer tools I verify that the request to said logo image is by HTTPS so I do not understand why I have this problem in console.

[image: https-http]

Site: www.menguz.com.mx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an HTTP image link in your fancybox javascript.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $.fancybox('<div class="pop"><img src="http://menguz.com.mx/img/vinos-y-licores-menguz-logo-1460428150.jpg" alt="" /><h3>Vinos y Licores Menguz sólo vende alcohol a mayores de edad.</h3><h3>Le pedimos responder con responsabilidad:</h3><div class="options"><ul class="buttons"><li><a href="http://google.com.mx" class="myButton">Salir, soy menor de 18 años</a></li><li><a href="#" class="myButton closeFancybox">Soy Mayor de 18 años</a></li></ul></div></div>', {
        'width': 500,
        'height': 250,
        'autoScale': true,
        'scrolling': 'si',
        'closeClick': false,
        'closeBtn': false,
        'keys': {
            close:
                null
        },
        'helpers': {
            overlay: {
                closeClick:
                    false
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks bro!